# PHP requirements of a 'echo' VS 'return'

Tags: php, return, echo

In a PHP function, sometimes I find that something can be echoed, yet it cannot be returned.

For example, this sucessfully echo's the result onto the page:

```
function get_page_id( $path ) {

global $mysqli;
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT state FROM country WHERE city = ?")) {
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $city);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($state);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->close();
    echo $state;
}

}
```

However, this function does not return the value:

```
function get_page_id( $path ) {

global $mysqli;
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT state FROM country WHERE city = ?")) {
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $city);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($state);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->close();
    return $state;
}

}
```

What makes a value able to be echoed but not returned?

$state variable is called elsewhere and is included as a global but is not included in the example. What is interesting is that when I change the function to return $state.''; it returns the result as I would expect it to, but only when I append the empty string does it do this. Why could that be?

Comment: What is $state, and where is it declared?

Comment: It should return ... are you sure sure you are call them the same way ?

Comment: Based on what code do you base this assumption? Have you tried `echo get_page_id(...)` using the function who returns a value?

Comment: @iMoses yes echo get_page_id() does work as you've suggested. I was using: die(get_page_id()); and that was not working, which doesn't make sense to me since echo does produce the desired result.

Comment: $city isn't defined in both functions. Doesn't seem to be "real code"...

Comment: When echoing a string the `echo` command executes **before** the `die` command. When returning a value and doing nothing with it, nothing will be printed.

Comment: Could it be something in the way you call them or use the returned result?  Could gettype($returnedResult) help?

Comment: Also, just in case, there's no return for the alternative case, when the if condition is false. Returning a crazy value or abnormally terminating there could help as well.

Comment: And if $state is global, that breaks encapsulation.  Your problem may be a side effect of that.  I'd consider refactoring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`However, this function does not return the value:` I cannot reproduce that behaviour

e.g.

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'localonly', 'localonly', 'test');
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') ' . $mysqli->connect_error);
}
setup($mysqli);

$state = get_page_id('acity');
echo 'state: ', $state;

function get_page_id( $city ) {
    global $mysqli;
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT state FROM tmp_country WHERE city = ?")) {
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $city);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($state);
        $stmt->fetch();
        $stmt->close();
        return $state;
    }
}


function setup($mysqli) {
    $mysqli->query('
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_country (
            id int auto_increment,
            city varchar(32),
            state varchar(32),
            primary key(id),
            unique key(city)
        )
    ') or die($mysqli->error);
    $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO tmp_country (city,state) VALUES ('acity','astate'),('bcity','bstate')") or die($mysqli->error);
}
```

prints `state: astate` on my machine as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The only example of a value that must be echo'd/printed and not returned is in certain AJAX applications, where the script being run is in a different thread and so has nowhere to 'return' a value to. In that case, the value must be output, where it is captured by the calling XHR function.

Your example doesn't declare a `$state` value anywhere. Neither of your examples will echo or return anything other than `null`.

Comment: `$stmt->bind_result($state);`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return and echo you just have to do:

```
echo $state;
return $state;
```

Returning a value and echoing it are two different and unrelated actions.